# Did Jet Just Die?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender

Jet appears to have died during his battle with Long Feng beneath Lake Laogai, particularly since he is never seen or heard from again. The possible death, however, occurs off-screen, and no mention of death *or* survival is ever made.

The ambiguity of the death is referenced later in *The Ember Island Players* as the group watches the play.

> Zuko: Did Jet just... die?
>
> Sokka: You know, it was really unclear.

[The Avatar Wikia](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Jet) claims death, but offers no citation other than the episode which is unclear to begin with.

**Is there any canon confirmation or word of god that Jet lived or died after the battle at Lake Laogai?**

Comment: If someone wants to take the time to come up with an edit that doesn't play the pronoun game with the title and still leaves the question as useful without spoiler blocking the whole thing, feel free - but I will roll back any suggestions that fail that.

Comment: How about, "What was the outcome of the battle beneath Lake Laogai?" I don't think that would reveal nearly as much information.

Comment: Jet's dead, baby. Jet's dead.

Answer (score 31):

In the DVD release, in the [Avatar Extras](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Avatar_Extras_(Book_Three:_Fire)) for "The Ember Island Players", a commentary bubble stated,

> "For the record: Jet is dead."

The authors also commented that Nickelodeon wouldn't let them depict a clear death.

Comment: Awesome. Any chance of a screenshot or an exact quote?

Comment: @phantom42 The quote is exact, you can check it in the linked page. However it should be noted that the texts in the extras where not written by the authors but by one of the writers: Joshua Hamilton. It's generally considered cannon, but some people dispute that.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the quote from the authors that you mentioned.

Comment: Did the comment go any deeper than that? I find the change interesting compared to Korra's Season 4, where at least two rather graphic deaths were depicted.

Comment: @k0pernikus, if I remember correctly, Season 4 of Korra was only available online, which also meant the team had less restrictions on content.

Answer (score 7):

In my annotated copy of *The Promise*, there is the following commentary:

[image: Photo of a comic with commentary, transcribed below. Comic shows Smellerbee shouting "Fire Nation Out!" and someone holding up a sign with Chinese writing.]

Transcript of the commentary (which is a bit difficult to read):

> **GLY**: The Freedom Fighters are such great characters.  **In an early draft, I had Jet here** alongside Smellerbee, Longshot, and Sneers.  I thought his fate was ambiguous enough that he could be brought back.  (And Sokka agrees with me.  Take a look at "The Ember Island Players.")  Nope.  The world of *Avatar* is not the Marvel universe.  Here, **dead means dead.**

(Longshot and Sneers are there too, just cropped out because of the image size limit.)

According to earlier commentary bits, "GLY" is Gene Luen Yang, who is credited with writing the script of this comic.  Along with the other answers, I think the authorial intent is pretty clear here.

If you only care for in-universe answers, Jet does not appear at any point in this comic, but he is also not mentioned by any of the characters as far as I can tell.  Smellerbee and the others re-formed the Freedom Fighters without him:

[image: Comic of Smellerbee greeting Aang with "Aang! We were hoping you would come! So what's the plan of attack? The Freedom Fighters are at your service!"]

I think it is implausible that they would have done so without even mentioning his name, were he still alive.

Answer (score 4):

Jet was hit by a pretty powerful blow, most likely causing internal damage, though it being a kid's show they couldn't show any blood coming from the mouth, which is usually what they do to show that someone is bleeding internally. I think longshot then does a mercy kill which is why he gets an arrow ready.

Answer (score 1):

We never actually see him die. During his last fight Jet gets hurt by Long Feng, they hint of his death when Toph says that Smellerbee is lying about Jet being okay but that is about it.
I think Nickelodeon just didn't want to say it in a children's show, because he was dead and if they say it kids might get upset but if you watch the show you see that Jet never comes back. There are also websites that say he was dead. 
Finding a canon answer might be hard but I think what was said in the show is enough to assume so!

Answer (score 0):

In the Legend of Korra comic named Turf Wars, there is a an opposing character that wields two curved end swords, the weapons are used the same that Jet had wielded them. The character also looked very similar, and his age seemed to match somewhere between Tenzin and Korra. Its quite possible that the character could have been Jet's son, which means he didn't die. (*Just a theory*)

Comment: It might be a good idea to [edit] in some images comparing the looks to back this up.

Answer (score -2):

*Spoiler Alert for Cowboy Bebop.

Since Jet is most likely an animation nod to Cowboy Bebop, (name obviously, but instead he looks like Spike, complete with "cigarette" wheat straw) it's appropriate to keep his "death" ambiguous. If you've watched the series, you'll get the really cool, clever Easter Egg.

Comment: Do you have any evidence except head canon that this is indeed a reference to Cowboy Bebop?

Answer (score -3):

According to [the wiki](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Jet):

> Jet insisted to Katara that he would be all right, but Toph sensed that he was lying. Smellerbee remained by Jet's side, crying, while Longshot notched an arrow and aimed it at the entrance of the room, ready to prevent any more attacks. Jet subsequently died from his serious internal injuries.

Also, from the same wiki page:

> Bryan and Mike explained in the commentary for "The Ember Island Players" that Nickelodeon was against showing kids being fatally wounded or outright killed, especially by a violent attack. It also could not be revealed during the rest of the story, so Toph sensing that Jet was lying about how he would be okay was how they chose to confirm it for the viewers. Also, in the Avatar Extras for "The Ember Island Players", a commentary bubble stated, "For the record: Jet is dead".

Comment: First, you just answered using the same wikia page I referenced in the question as being unreliable. Second, you provided the same unreliable information as other answers, as there is fan-contention regarding the canon of the information in the commentary bubbles.